# Schedule assignment, Java current time between to times that are parse from a schedule

Tags: java, parsing, if-statement, time, processing

I'm new here and I already have a question.

I'm making a assignment for school (in Processing with Java), we are loading a schedule from a txt file. 
And I need to make a visualisation from it, it's going good but I'm stuck at one point.

I want to make a if statement, to see if the current time is between the Start time and end time. I did parse the start time and End time from the txt file and I can call the current time. But i can't find or know the if statement. can someone help?

Parts of my code ( i can't show everything because i have 6 tabs) :

```
**//From the main tab**
int s = second();  // Values from 0 - 59
int mi = minute();  // Values from 0 - 59
int h = hour();    // Values from 0 - 23
int d = day();     // Values from 1 - 31
int mo = month();  // values from 1 - 12
int y = year();

// searching all data from Table, comparing location with roomsTTH, if its        the same check iff itint(random(20)), 20's free 
for (TableRow singleRow : tableRooster.rows()) {
ParseInfo parse = new ParseInfo(singleRow); 
for (Room roomToCheck : roomsTTH) {
  if (parse.location == roomToCheck.id) {
    if (roomToCheck.available) {

      if ( y == parseInt(parse.year)) {
        if (mo == parseInt(parse.month)) {
          if ( d == parseInt(parse.day)) {
           // if ( isBetween = currentTime.after(parse.startTime) && currantTime.before(parse.endTime)) {

            //  occupied = true; 
            //  Floor.maxRooms ++;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
 // }

**//From tab Parse**
 //StartTime
 String startTime;


  //EndTime
  String endTime;


  TableRow myTableRow;

  ParseInfo(TableRow tableRow) {
    parseRow(tableRow);
  }
  // Parse data into variables
  void parseRow(TableRow row) {

// Divide the parse location to level and room
this.location = row.getString("Location");
this.level = this.location.substring(5, 6);
this.room = this.location.substring(8, 9);

// Divide the parse start date to year, month, day
this.date = row.getString("Start date");
this.day = this.date.substring(9, 10);
this.month = this.date.substring(6, 7);
this.year = this.date.substring(0, 3);

// Parse Start time & End time 
this.startTime = row.getString("Start time");
this.endTime = row.getString("End time");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your dates are stored as `String` values. String values don't have a concept of whether they are *before* or *after* each other, so you have to do the comparison yourself. You have two options:

**Option 1**: Compare the `String` values alphabetically. Something like this:

```
String date1 = "2015/10/24";
String date2 = "2015/10/25";
if(date1.compareTo(date2) < 0){
   //date 1 is before date2
}
else if(date1.compareTo(date2) > 0){
   //date 1 is after date2
}
else{
   //they are the same date
}
```

**Option 2**: If that won't work for some reason (if the dates are in different formats, for example), then you can use Java's [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class to parse the date `String`s into [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) objects. Something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date date1 = sdf.parse("2015/10/24");
Date date2 = sdf.parse("2015/10/25");

if(date1.before(date2)){
   //date 1 is before date2
}
else if(date1.after(date2)){
   //date 1 is after date2
}
else{
   //they are the same date
}
```

Comment: You are right, and I understand that. but i need to do this with time. With the date, the date works just fine. I need to know how i can see if the string type (yes a string, because its from a txt file it is a string) that the current time (15:48) is between the start time  or end time.

Comment: @Conijntjuh Both options would work fine with time Strings as well. They're the same thing.